# Yammer REST API -RealTime Api

Tags: yammer

I try to research realTime api with yammer document.But when I browse "https://developer.yammer.com/realtime",it redirect to "https://developer.yammer.com/realtime-deprecated". Does it mean yammer will not support realTime api in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Starting August 2014 we are removing the Realtime API from the documentation.  While the Realtime API will continue to be supported and work, it will no longer be available on http://developer.yammer.com/.

We decided to remove it from our documentation because it no longer fits into our longer-term strategy and, while it will still be supported for the foreseeable future, we did not want new developers using it. Also, it’s been available for about 4 years and usage is relatively low.